# Replacement for md5 module in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, md5, hashlib

Is there any other module for md5?

Answer (score 66):

It is in hashlib

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5('asd'.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 4):

It has been deprecated since version 2.5. You must use [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/hashlib.html).

Answer (score 3):

From: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/

MD5 have been replaced by the 'hashlib' module.