# How to get MD5 sum of a string using python?

Tags: python, md5, flickr

In the [Flickr API docs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.web.html), you need to find the MD5 sum of a string to generate the `[api_sig]` value.

How does one go about generating an MD5 sum from a string?

Flickr's example:

string: `000005fab4534d05api_key9a0554259914a86fb9e7eb014e4e5d52permswrite`

MD5 sum: `a02506b31c1cd46c2e0b6380fb94eb3d`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, you do not need to install this (and library in PyPI is very old), it is now a part of the standard libraries: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 297, accepted):

For Python 2.x, use python's [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("000005fab4534d05api_key9a0554259914a86fb9e7eb014e4e5d52permswrite")
print m.hexdigest()
```

Output: `a02506b31c1cd46c2e0b6380fb94eb3d`

Comment: Don't try to use `hashlib.md5().update('your string').hexdigest()`, it won't work since `update()` returns None. If you want a one line solution, use Mark Longair's answer.

Comment: @ChristopherManning m.hexdigest() returns a 32 character long digest. How to get a 16 character long digest?

Comment: @Darwesh it's 32 characters because it's the hex representation, do a `m.digest_size` on top of this code, internal digest is already 16 bytes.

Comment: @Darwesh you can simply slice the string `m.hexdigest()[:16]`

Comment: @Darwesh According to [RFC 1321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1321.html), the md5 is always 16 bytes. If you just want a 16 character long digest, you can do a slice as Baris Demiray said.

Comment: work like charm, i used it to generate my hash password on db

Comment: @yussan It's not recmmeded to use MD5 for password hashes nowadays. THey can be bruteforced very fast, so it offers little protection.

Comment: The correct way in Python 3.7 is `m.update( "text".encode('utf-8') )` otherwise an error will come out!

Answer (score 793):

You can do the following:

**Python 2.x**

```
import hashlib
print hashlib.md5("whatever your string is").hexdigest()
```

---

**Python 3.x**

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5("whatever your string is".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

---

However in this case you're probably better off using this helpful Python module for interacting with the Flickr API:

- http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi

... which will deal with the authentication for you.

Official documentation of [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)

Comment: hexdigest() returns a 32 character long digest. How to get a 16 character long digest?

Comment: Nice answer! May I ask why in Python 2 we don't need to do utf-8 encoding, however in Python 3 we need to do the encoding. Thanks. @Mark Longair

Comment: @JeffHu, because `hashlib.md5` expects [a bytes-like-object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object)

Comment: The Python 3 version should be used in Python 2 as well.

@JeffHu expanding on what @MaxU said, the md5 function takes a bytestring and does not accept unicode.  Python 3 is (correctly) strict/explicit, and so a an str (`""`) is unicode and has to be encoded to a bytestring.

Strings in python2 can be interpreted as either a btyestring or unicode string, and passing a str (`""`) string is interpreted as a bytestring.  If the string has unicode characters, this will raise an Exception.  Encoding a bytestring will leave ascii characters untouched and convert unicode correctly

Comment: Actually, using the Python 3 version is the only way to be sure the answer is correct, especially in Python 2:
Python 3: `hashlib.md5("\u00f1".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() -> '94e9342ecbb1458b6043ecd3bfcbc192'`
Python 2: `hashlib.md5("\u00f1").hexdigest() -> '8d70428c396cafbf791f79f1c5172cd7'`
Python 2: `hashlib.md5(u"\u00f1".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() -> '94e9342ecbb1458b6043ecd3bfcbc192'`

Comment: For Python 3, is there a reason to use .encode('utf-8') instead of .encode() without parameter? It works great without the 'utf-8' string like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954602/replacement-for-md5-module-in-python-3/4954618#4954618
By the way, I read Python 3 is easier than Python 2 but here it is not the case since the .encode() extra step is not needed at all in Python 2...

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`b` character in front of a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal):

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5(b"Hello MD5").hexdigest())
print(hashlib.md5("Hello MD5".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

---

Out:

```
e5dadf6524624f79c3127e247f04b548
e5dadf6524624f79c3127e247f04b548
```

Comment: What about in front of a string variable? This syntax doesn't work for `b'string_variable`.

Comment: @flwJlxSzApHEZII, try  string_variable.encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using the MD5 implementation in [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)? Note that hashing algorithms typically act on *binary* data rather than *text* data, so you may want to be careful about which character encoding is used to convert from text to binary data before hashing.

The *result* of a hash is also binary data - it looks like Flickr's example has then been converted into text using hex encoding. Use the `hexdigest` function in hashlib to get this.

Comment: hexdigest() returns a 32 character long digest. How to get a 16 character long digest?

Comment: @Darwesh: Well yes, MD5 is 128 bits, which is 32 characters in hex. If you want a smaller digest, you'll need a 64-bit digest. That will be pretty weak though...

Answer (score 12):

Use hashlib.md5 in Python 3.

```
import hashlib

source = '000005fab4534d05api_key9a0554259914a86fb9e7eb014e4e5d52permswrite'.encode()
md5 = hashlib.md5(source).hexdigest() # returns a str
print(md5) # a02506b31c1cd46c2e0b6380fb94eb3d
```

If you need byte type output, use `digest()` instead of `hexdigest()`.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on windows 10:

```py
import hashlib

print(hashlib.md5("string to encode".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Try This 
import hashlib
user = input("Enter text here ")
h = hashlib.md5(user.encode())
h2 = h.hexdigest()
print(h2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Try with

```
#python3
import hashlib
rawdata = "put your data here"
sha = hashlib.sha256(str(rawdata).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() #For Sha256 hash
print(sha)
mdpass = hashlib.md5(str(sha).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() #For MD5 hash
print(mdpass)
```

Answer (score 2):

simple toolkit：

```
In [62]: import hashlib
    ...:
    ...: def make_md5(data: str) -> str:
    ...:     md5_value = hashlib.md5(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    ...:     return md5_value
    ...:

In [63]:

In [63]: make_md5("123-123-123-123")
Out[63]: '779e9814651491eae36438dff100820d'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get results that are easy to do arithmetic with (ie. modulo), you could try this:

```
import hashlib
import struct

struct.unpack('iiii', hashlib.md5(b'hi').digest())
```

Which yields:

```
(1552610889, 753701764, -2104888309, 1006379292)
```

Comment: This might not produce consistent results, depending on the internal implementation / internal data structure of `hashlib.md5()`. You can also produce a list of numbers with: `list(hashlib.md5(b'hi').digest())`

Comment: If you need portability, you can set the endian-ness.