# How do I calculate the md5 checksum of a string in starbasic macro (openoffice macro)?

Tags: macros, md5, openoffice-basic

I am trying to make an OpenOfficeWriter StarBasic-Macro Program, that turns wiki source code to Open office Writer. I need  a starbasic macro, that generates the MD5 checksum. There is a MD5Thumbprint  in the Documentation for OpenOffice, so I suppose you can compute the MD5 in a Open Office starbasic macro using some kind of macro code. This is what I'm looking for.

I suppose I have to use the XCertificate Interface in the security module, but I don't know how the macro code should be. So I need a Open Office starbasic macro command or code like: `stringMD5=s.md5()`, where will be a string (for example something like "Douglas C-47 Skytrain.jpg") and stringMD5 should be a string or something that I can make to a string (in this example the outcome in the end should be the string "40decfb5f1be8bca1e56c8a853027941", which is the MD5 for the String "Douglas C-47 Skytrain.jpg").

I would like to avoid using Python (see:[How to get MD5 sum of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297448/how-to-get-md5-sum-of-a-string#5297495)) and create a starbasic macro instead. If somebody has a tip, I will be of course very glad. George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cryptographic extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/cryptographic-hash-functions-uno-component-openofficeorg) seems to do what you want.  However it may not work in recent versions of OpenOffice.

Otherwise, write the macro in a language such as [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297448/how-to-get-md5-sum-of-a-string) or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash) that can compute MD5 using a library.

Related: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&p=391985

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  If this answer was helpful, then please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: tried already, but i m completely  new und dont have points to do it....

Comment: Reputation is not necessary to do it.  Did you read the instructions in the link?