# Django Randomly generated words (passphrase or mimetic word)

Tags: python, django, passphrase

I'm looking for a django package that generate mimetic words.
 here is the scenario, when a new user finished the registration he will be redirected to a new page where a random sentence of 5 words appears, the user must save this sentence to use it when he want to reset his account password.
** i'm no going to use the email password reset process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate a md5 hash using hashlib? It is very easy to implement and probably more secure than the 5 random words. You can check out how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297448/how-to-get-md5-sum-of-a-string)  Take a look at Mark Longair's answer, he does it in one line.

So then you generate the hash and save it in the database and the user also keeps a copy somewhere.