# How to calculate md5 of string in Python similar as "crypto/md5" in Go

Tags: python, go, md5

I know there is [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) in Python, but I want to achieve the same result as in Go below:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("12345")
    fmt.Println("sum ", md5.Sum(data))
}
```

As [func md5.Sum](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/) described, it calculates "MD5 checksum of the data". 
However, I don't find any similar function in Python.

Is there any way to achieve `md5.Sum` in Python as in Go?

The output of program above is **a slice other than a string**:

```
sum  [32 44 185 98 172 89 7 91 150 75 7 21 45 35 75 112]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297448/how-to-get-md5-sum-of-a-string

Comment: thx, I have seen that, it couldn't do md5.sum for data

Comment: Here's a one-liner: `from hashlib import md5;print(md5(b'12345').hexdigest())`. Output: `827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b`. If you do `echo -n '12345' | md5sum` in Bash you get the same output.

Comment: thanks, please check my output part:  the output for Go is a list other than a string ,so simply call python API not work

Comment: MD5 outputs 16 bytes. Your Go code is outputting those 16 bytes as numbers in the range 0..255. And it's easy to get Python to create a list of numbers like that from the MD5 sum.  But I don't see why your Go code prints those numbers from "12345" . Can you show how the original `data` prints?

Comment: I just tested my code with `b"These pretzels are making me thirsty."`, the same data as in the example in the Go docs you linked, and I get the same output as what's printed there, `b0804ec967f48520697662a204f5fe72`, or in numeric form `[176, 128, 78, 201, 103, 244, 133, 32, 105, 118, 98, 162, 4, 245, 254, 114]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on PM 2Ring's solution, here is a working program,

```
from hashlib import md5

hexv = md5(b'12345').hexdigest()
l = [str(int(i+j,16)) for i, j in zip(hexv[::2], hexv[1::2])]
print("sum [" + ", ".join(l)+"]")
```

This prints,

```
sum [130, 124, 203, 14, 234, 138, 112, 108, 76, 52, 161, 104, 145, 248, 78, 123]
```

Comment: There's a _much_ easier way to do that conversion! Just convert the `bytes` returned by `md5` into a list, like this: `list(md5(b'12345').digest())`, or in Python 2 `list(bytearray(md5(b'12345').digest()))`. FWIW, I didn't post a full answer because I'm _still_ waiting for the OP to clarify why they get `[32 44 185 98 172 89 7 91 150 75 7 21 45 35 75 112]` instead of the list that you got.