# What is equivalent php encode method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what the php method equivalent python that i should use in python. I tried to generate some code but it wrong and doesn’t work. Can anyone help me convert this code php to python

PHP:

```
tracking = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40));
id = substr(md5(tracking), 16);
```

Python

```
tracking = os.urandom(40)
print(tracking)

>>> YidceGM1XHhjZVx4MTBceGVkX1x4OGFxXHhkN0NcdFhQU1x4ZTdceDA0Mip7KVx4OGRceDFjXHhhYlx4ODdAcFpceGVmXHg4ZXVcdFZHdFdceGM2OnZceGUyXFxceDFlJw==
```

But correctly code length must be 56 but in python generated so long

example correct tracking :

```
PldikuqQF1/acrFfnfkBr6pIFjRZ9eLzsgQf6hpRVm/e8s1kmOrqjw==
```

```
X2g1P0ORzhlyDCUzSrS2o2n8EgZYpXvzBkNMMdEyNegqjr8GbTlOGA==
```

example correct id :

```
a3c6b613c95f4ea9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.urandom()` provides no guarantee the bytes it produces are compatible with base64. (Props to you for using something so secure!) In order to convert the bytestream, you need to first use `base64.b64encode()`. It can then be decoded to utf-8 for printing or other use.

```py
>>> import base64, os
>>> print(base64.b64encode(os.urandom(40)).decode('utf-8'))
h0nsWdcU6rYw3BJD3NLbq5MuqF6n7btAZuT14TipHOA9RYRZEuqj2g==
```

For md5 encoding, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297483/7431860) recommends `hashlib.md5()` to encode.